# Module not found: Can't resolve './components/ImageItem/ImageItem' in 'C:\Users\main\projects\mobile\node_modules\react-native-image-viewing\dist'

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I have error When I start running expo. I am trying to start a ongoing project and not able to figure out the problem. I tried yarn start, tried deleting node modules and installing it back, but couldn't resolve the problem

Module not found: Can't resolve '../../../Image/Image' in 'node_modules\react-native\Libraries

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "2.4.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "5.9.2",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "1.6.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.15.0",
    "expo": "^38.0.10",
    "expo-asset": "~8.1.7",
    "expo-constants": "~9.1.1",
    "expo-font": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-image-picker-multiple": "^1.2.0",
    "expo-intent-launcher": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-location": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-network": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~9.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.5.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.2.10",
    "geolib": "^3.2.1",
    "lottie-ios": "3.1.8",
    "lottie-react-native": "~2.6.1",
    "mobx": "^5.15.4",
    "mobx-react": "^6.2.2",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^2.0.6",
    "object-to-formdata": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "~0.62.2",
    "react-native-android-dialog-picker": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.33.3",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
    "react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-lightbox": "^0.8.1",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "~3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.0",
    "react-native-star-view": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-step-indicator": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
    "react-native-swipeable-modal": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.14.4",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.10.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-native-web-swiper": "^2.1.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.9",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^4.0.2",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.2.12",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.4.0",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.8.13",
    "rn-material-dropdown": "^0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.9.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "square-mobile-app",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: this probably because you have typo when import variable

Comment: Could you post file where this error happened ?